# PHP system() command not showing output on the browser

Tags: php, ssl

I am using PHP, to execute a system command and show the output on the browser, but the browser shows nothing, I am using xampp on mac .

This is my code:

```
<?php

system("curl --insecure -v https:example.com 2>&1 | awk 'BEGIN { cert=0 } /^\* SSL connection/ { cert=1 } /^\*/ { if (cert) print }' | grep 'SSL connection'");


?>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the point of issuing an external command pipe to stablish an HTTP connection? That basically makes error checking much harder because you move all logic to a black box. In any case, you should at least use the [`$return_var` parameter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php#refsect1-function.system-parameters) to figure out if system call worked.

Comment: Yeah man, I figured that out later, I am using curl with PHP, instead of issuing a system command to get the encryption algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a problem with the `system()` command itself. At the end you expect to display a grep filtered string which does not exist, so that is the reason why there is no output.

The problem lies in an invalid URL passed to CURL.

Change
`https:example.com`
to
`https://example.com` # add forward slashes

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but instead I used curl within PHP, instead of issuing a system command, cause it's not secure .

Comment: @achkar69 PHP's Curl extension is basically a wrapper to the same exact library that curl command-line is using.